# Mongokit How do I specify a key in a dict which is in a list as a required field?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongokit

I'm using mongokit and I have a structure similar to this in my document.

```
class MyDoc(Document):
    structure = {
        'sections': [{
            'title': unicode,
            'description': unicode
        }]
    }

    required_fields = []
```

I want to make `description` a required field in this document. I know nested keys can be accessed via the dot notation, but `sections.description` does not work. How do I achieve what I want?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? update sections.description? find a document with sections.description that matches your query? or are you trying to ensure required fields are used?

If you want sections.description to be a required field, you'll have to use a schema to ensure required fields are included in your models. I use mongoose in my nodejs applications to ensure strict adherence to schemas. Mongo currently doesn't have field level validation, however I know that it is in the works for future releases.

Comment: I'm trying to let `description` be a required field and I'm using [mongokit](https://github.com/namlook/mongokit) to provide a schema for that. This is a question specific to mongokit.

Comment: It looks like you can only set default value on an embedded doc after 0.7, but not make it required. You might need to fork mongoKit to make this work appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `sections.$.description`

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Comment: may have jumped the gun - thought you were looking for a query to access the field.